# How to convert UTF8 multibyte character into byte string? Perl

Tags: perl

I have a multibyte character ''. How can I convert this into '\360\245\242\245'?
`use Devel::Peek;` gives me that information, but it only prints it to console...

Comment: Do you want the 4-char string returned by `"\360\245\242\245"`, or the 16-char string returned by `"\\360\\245\\242\\245"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
use utf8;
my $s = "";   # Or "\x{258A5}", or chr(0x258A5), or ...
```

**If you want want the 4-char string returned by `"\360\245\242\245"`**

In this case, you are asking to have the string encoded using UTF-8.

```
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );
encode_utf8($s)
```

**If you want the 16-char string returned by `"\\360\\245\\242\\245"`**

In this case, you are asking for a "human-readable" representation of the UTF-8 encoding of the string.

```
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );
join "", map sprintf("\\%o"), split //, encode_utf8($s)
```

Alternatives:

- ```
  use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );
  sprintf("%vo", encode_utf8($s))   # 360.245.242.245
  ```
- ```
  use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );
  sprintf("%vX", encode_utf8($s))   # F0.A5.A2.A5
  ```
- ```
  use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
  local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
  Dumper($s)                        # "\x{258a5}"
  ```
- ```
  use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
  use Encode       qw( encode_utf8 );
  local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
  Dumper(encode_utf8($s))           # "\360\245\242\245"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Unicode::UTF8 qw( encode_utf8 );

my $x = "";
print encode_utf8($x);
```

Output:

```
 C:\...\Temp> perl t.pl|xxd
 00000000: f0a5 a2a5                                ....
```

Comment: What is in that box character that my browser cannot render?

Comment: The usual use of `use utf8` is to allow non-ASCII characters to be used within strings and identifiers without a corresponding `utf8_encode` or similar. Offering an unidentifiable splat on the screen is a *misuse* of the facility, and you should know better.

Comment: The answer contains contains the appropriate level of detail and explanation given the content of the question. "*Here, I have a character. How can I get the UTF-8 encoding of that?*" ... "*Use the `encode_utf8` function from the `Unicode::UTF8` module*". Whether this is said in English or code is irrelevant (or ought to be to people who consider themselves to be programmers).

Comment: And, the glyph displays perfectly in my Vim window and Firefox (both the question and my answer). You might want to consider a more modern font configuration.